# Drupal or Framework for SaaS Booking Application

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, drupal-7, saas

I'm going to build SaaS Booking Application like www.redbus.in and www.bitlasoft.com. The application will act also like search engine(www.hipmunk.com) for bus ticket availability from other online bus operators who provide seat availability API.

I don't know whether I should choose Drupal or not. Should I develop application with Zend framework? I'm not the programmer but just owner of the application. I need to decide on development framework. Please suggest me on this issue.

Thanks you all in advance. I'll greatly appreciate your answer and it'll help me to make good decision.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not the programmer, then you should focus on finding the writing programmer/dev company for the job, instead of picking specific tools. Let them use the tools they feel are best for your application.

Comment: Thanks but I want to get best solution that can be scalable, good performance, modular and so on. So I think I should decide on which development platform for my development team.The choice of language and platform effect on cost of development.

Comment: I agree with Tim. Unless you know how to program yourself, then it isn't effective to make decisions about specific tools. A programmer would be more able to determine the tools effectiveness for the current job and planned development in the future.